# What would a map of the world look like if lat/longs were treated as projected coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I'm not quite sure if I'm phrasing this right. It's just occurred to me that lat/longs are two dimensional coordinates like any other projected coordinate system, so it's presumably possible to create a two dimensional map based on these unprojected coordinates.

It would obviously be centred on the point (0,0) (off the west coast of Africa, on the equator), and the 180 meridian would be exactly on the left and right borders.

Is there a name for this kind of "non-projection"? Presumably there are images of it, but I'm just not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the standard term for this is an "unprojected map". There's an example here: http://www.colorado.edu/geography/gcraft/notes/mapproj/gif/unproj.gif

Comment: aka [Plate Carrée](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003r0000003r000000)

Comment: And "equirectangular, equidistant cylindrical, simple cylindrical, or rectangular" apparently!

Comment: It looks like Geographic. Kind of ok at working out what's left/right above/below something but not much good at anything else... you couldn't take an accurate bearing or measurement.